# Jupyter notebook does not have "run" button (Windows 10)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run Jupyter notebook on my Windows 10 machine. I installed it by running the following list of commands from cmd:

```
pip install Ipython
python -m pip install ipykernel
pip install jupyterlab
```

And run from the command prompt

```
jupyter notebook
```

It launches and seems OK, but it only allows me to open and edit files without an option to run them. In screenshot, one can see how my jupyter window looks like. There is no "run" button.
I checked `jupyter kernelspec list` and this is what I have there

```
Available kernels:
  python3    c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

Also, when it closes, it prints

```
[I 14:46:12.194 NotebookApp] Shutting down 0 kernels
```

As if kernels were not even launched (most likely they were not).

Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong?

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiaOW.png)

**CASE RESOLVED**

Apparently, jupyter does not recognize other extensions as `.ipynb`, so if you try to open something other than that it will fail to provide "run" button. However, it was not the end of the story. Even after I opened a file with proper extension, it could not run it for some other reasons. The way to fix it was just to install [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) and then run `jupyter notebook` from anaconda prompt.

Comment: I followed this advice  https://superuser.com/questions/1605390/cannot-run-py-files-from-jupyter-notebook but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

For newbies:
If you had this problem,
Check out your file extension again. It should be .py not .ipynb.

Jupyter will open .py as a text to edit and **will not show** the RUN button.

Solution:
Open the file, copy what's in it, then open a new notebook and paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Anaconda to run Jupyter Notebook without any problem. Install the anaconda. After the installation you can run the jupyter notebook without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think I had the same issue.
When you opened jupyter notebook, you see "files" "running" "clusters"
command bar. Naturally, you go under "files" to locate and open your notebook file. That is the dead end you are in. On the right-hand top corner, you see the status bar "plain text." You cannot change this status.
The trick is before you open the file, in the first window, you notice the status "new." You press this botton, then an option of "Python3." Choose the option then that will take you the ready-to-run status. From there you can open your file to run. Try.